# Normalizing IP addresses

Tags: java, python, regex, bash

Before I go ahead and write something myself is anyone aware of a library that can normalize a set of IP addresses. I manage an application where access is based on a range of IP address supplied from our clients. Most often this is small, but sometimes this list is 1,000+ horribly presented IP addresses.

#### for example

```
#INPUT                  #TO             #OUTPUT
192.168.0-10.*          ->        192.168.0.0-192.168.10.255
192.168.15.0-64         ->        192.168.15.0-192.168.15.64
192.10-15.*.*           ->        192.10.0.0-192.15.255.255
192.168.1.1             ->        192.168.1.1-192.168.1.1
#YES, last case needed too, 
#the scripit I have to convert to a CIDR range needs  start and stop
```

This would preferably be done in python, but java or some sort of shell script would work too.
After wards I already have a script I've written to convert to the CIDR range and store these in our permissions table. I'm really just tried of doing this by hand several times a year. I think it is time to automate this a bit, just don't want to reinvent the wheel here. It seems this might be a common enough problem

Comment: @CarlNorum I think OP is just asking if something that would do this already exists before he goes out and writes his own

Comment: this question is more about does something exist before I write something myself. So, I've tried several google queries

Comment: Does it always has one part with `-` and all parts after that with `*`?

Comment: Isn't this just a pretty minor string processing problem?  If the octet is a single number, put the number in both outputs (i.e., before and after the `-`) - if it's a `*`, put 0 and 255, and if it's got a `-` in it, put the two surrounding numbers.

Comment: at the heart of this yes, its minor. But hardly trivial. Error checking would also be useful. A further personal customization would be checking the validity of the range across what is already connected. In applications such as mine we rely on people that have no idea what they're doing supplying IP to connect. Meaning I get, local addresses and mistyped ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers were helpfull, but neither answer my question. Which was if there exisited a library to do this already. I haven't found one. It may be a worthwhile method to include of one of the other libraries that exist that focus on IPs. Adam's Iptools was something that I  found before asking this question.

My output did change a bit. I ended up returning a CIDR address and not a range. A few things could be simplified, and cleaned up. Also some error checking would be helpful. But this is what I used, with my rusty python and everything.

```
def normalize(ip):
    if '/' in ip: 
        return [ip]

    ocets = [ocet.replace(' ','') for ocet in ip.split('.')]
    if len(ocets) == 4: ocets += ocets
    if len(ocets) == 7: 
        if (re.search('-',ocets[3])):
            for i,v in enumerate(ocets[3:]):
                if i == 0:
                    last = ocets[4]
                    ocets[3],ocets[4] = ocets[3].split('-')
                else:
                    if 4+i < len(ocets):
                        newVal = last
                        last = ocets[4+i]
                        ocets[4+i] = newVal
                    else: 
                        ocets.append(last)

    if len(ocets) != 8: 
        return 'ERROR WITH: %s not right size %d' % ('.'.join(ocets),len(ocets))
    for i,ocet in enumerate(ocets):
        if (re.search('\*',ocet)): 
            ocets[i] = '0'
            ocets[i+4] = '255'        


        if (re.search('-',ocets[i])): 
            ocets[i],ocets[i+4] = ocets[i].split('-')[0:2]
    newIP = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs('.'.join(ocets[0:4]) ,'.'.join(ocets[4:]))
    return newIP
```

Answer (score 1):

regexp solution in javascript (it is a console language for windows ;-)

```
function(addr) {
    addr.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, "\$1").replace(/\*/, "0") + '-' +
    addr.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, "\$2").replace(/\*/, "255")
}
```

functional solution in python (python is foreign language for me)

```
pairs = [s == '*' ? (0, 255) : s.split('-')[0,-1] for s in addr.split('.')];
[s[0] for s in pairs].join('.')+'-'+[s[1] for s in pairs].join('.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at Python IP tools:

http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/

Seems to have most of what you need, and you can always extend it if there's something it doesn't do....